# Nuxt.js async head meta values

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to create a unique page for my users, and I want their usernames to be in the URL like `https://mycure.com/gaben`.

I achieved this using dynamic routing and the `head()` method. Everything is ok if the information are static. However, I am making a REST call to my API to provide the user data, which will be the value of the head title and head description.

Since the request is async, the default value of the title and description in the header are not being rendered in the HTML properly.

So it's like a race condition between the rendering of the content and the async call to fetch user data.

Here's my current `head` method:

```
head () {
  // async call for user data
  return this.initMetaHead();
}
```

**Actual Flow**

1. Render page - default title value
2. Async call
3. Set new title - not reflected to the actual html when page source is viewed

**Desired Flow**

4. Async call
5. Render page with proper title and description

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide us some code?

Comment: You could use async/await ?